# MS SQL Server - Adding computed column with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, calculated-columns

I am trying to add computed column with subquery which will transform Unix timestamp to regular `DateTime` format, using this query, but there is error.
Using Azure SQL Server.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.FP_Contacts_CRM 
    ADD DWH_propertieslastmodifieddatevalue 
        AS (SELECT DATEADD(S, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(propertieslastmodifieddatevalue, 10)), '1970-01-01')
            FROM dbo.FP_Contacts_CRM)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Comment: your error already said Subqueries not  allowed

Comment: Also this subquery may return more than one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use subqueries for Calculated Columns. Instead, just give the formula only.

```
alter table dbo.FP_Contacts_CRM 
add DWH_propertieslastmodifieddatevalue as 
    (
        DATEADD(S, 
                    CONVERT(int,LEFT(propertieslastmodifieddatevalue, 10))
                    , '1970-01-01')
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, subqueries are not allowed for  the computed column declaration.

But for the original question, you can use use scalar functions like below.

```
DATEADD(S, CONVERT(int,LEFT(<yourdtcolumn>, 10)), '1970-01-01')
```